# how to use select along with insert query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Hi I'm a rookie to Mysql. I have table called course(c_id,c_name). I have inserted c_id and left c_name blank. Now how can I enter the c_name for that particular c_id using select statement inside the insert query ?

Comment: ìt is very unclear what you asking

Answer (score 2):

Use a simple update query, since you've already inserted the row. E.g. (replace x with your id):

```
 update course set c_name = "your value" where c_id = x
```

Comment: get last inserted id using LAST_INSERT_ID  that is c_id and updated that particular column in your case c_name.